# Encrypt/decrypt with XOR in PHP

Tags: php, encryption

I am studying encryption. And I got a problem like this:

After I XOR plaintext with a key, I get a crypt, "010e010c15061b4117030f54060e54040e0642181b17", as hex type. If I want to get plaintext from this crypt, what should I do in PHP?

I tried convert it to string/int and after that take them to XOR with the key (three letters). But it doesn't work.

This is the code:

```
function xor_this($string) {

    // Let's define our key here
    $key = 'fpt';

    // Our plaintext/ciphertext
    $text = $string;

    // Our output text
    $outText = '';

    // Iterate through each character
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($text); )
    {
        for($j=0; $j<strlen($key); $j++,$i++)
        {
            $outText .= ($text[$i] ^ $key[$j]);
            //echo 'i=' . $i . ', ' . 'j=' . $j . ', ' . $outText{$i} . '<br />'; // For debugging
        }
    }
    return $outText;
}

function strToHex($string)
{
    $hex = '';
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($string); $i++)
    {
        $hex .= dechex(ord($string[$i]));
    }
    return $hex;
}

function hexToStr($hex)
{
    $string = '';
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($hex)-1; $i+=2)
    {
        $string .= chr(hexdec($hex[$i].$hex[$i+1]));
    }
    return $string;
}

$a = "This is the test";
$b = xor_this($a);
echo xor_this($b), '-------------';
//
$c = strToHex($b);
$e = xor_this($c);
echo $e, '++++++++';
//
$d = hexToStr($c);
$f = xor_this($d);
echo $f, '=================';
```

And this is the result:

> This is the test-------------
>
> PHP Notice:  Uninitialized string offset: 29 in C:\
>   Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.php on line 210 PHP Stack trace: PHP
>   1. {main}() C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.php:0 PHP   2. xor_this() C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.php:239
>
> Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 29 in
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.p hp on line 210
>
> Call Stack:
>       0.0005     674280   1. {main}() C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.php:0
>       0.0022     674848   2. xor_this() C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.php:23 9
>
> UBE^A►WEAVA►WEAV@◄WEARAFWECWB++++++++
>
> This is zs$fs☺=================

Why? The "UBE^A►WEAVA►WEAV@◄WEARAFWECWB++++++++" is the result, which I got trouble in my real work.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this:

```
function xor_this($string) {

    // Let's define our key here
    $key = ('magic_key');

    // Our plaintext/ciphertext
    $text = $string;

    // Our output text
    $outText = '';

    // Iterate through each character
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($text); )
    {
        for($j=0; ($j<strlen($key) && $i<strlen($text)); $j++,$i++)
        {
            $outText .= $text{$i} ^ $key{$j};
            //echo 'i=' . $i . ', ' . 'j=' . $j . ', ' . $outText{$i} . '<br />'; // For debugging
        }
    }
    return $outText;
}
```

**Basically to revert text back (even numbers are in) you can use the same function:**

```
$textToObfuscate = "Some Text 12345";
$obfuscatedText = xor_this($textToObfuscate);
$restoredText = xor_this($obfuscatedText);
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Cause my key is only 3 letters, so the Crypt must be divide into group of 3 before xor. And one more thing, the Crypt is hexa, so we must convert it firstly - I think that but not sure - It is my problem :)

Comment: Oh, I understood your code. This code doesn't care the length of key. But the crypt is a hexa, do we need to convert it before xor with key?

Comment: You can use this http://ditio.net/2008/11/04/php-string-to-hex-and-hex-to-string-functions/

Comment: I tried and it work with string does not have "space". with the space, it got problem.

Comment: @OneManCrew   You have a small error  $obfuscatedText = $xor_this($textToObfuscate);   should be $obfuscatedText = xor_this($textToObfuscate);.A good encryption code,keep up the good work.

Comment: Note that the current implementation will run in an infinite loop if the key is an empty string (relevant especially if the function is modified to receive the key as a parameter).

Answer (score 20):

Even easier:

```
function xor_string($string, $key) {
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) 
        $string[$i] = ($string[$i] ^ $key[$i % strlen($key)]);
    return $string;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the code above i created 2 functions to xor encode a JSON string using javascript and then decode it on server side using PHP.

> **!!! Important:** If you will have characters different from ASCII(like Chinese, Cyrillic, Symbols...) in your JSON string, you
>   must **either** write some code in PHP or JS to fix how these
>   characters are encoded/decoded (ord/chr in PHP produce different
>   results in comparison with JS charCodeAt/String.fromCharCode) **or**
>   just base64_encode the JSON string and after that xor encode it.

Personally i use `xor_string(base64_encode(JSON.stringify(object)), 'xor_key')` in JS and on PHP side:

```
$json = json_decode(base64_decode(
                        xor_string(file_get_contents("php://input"), 'xor_key')
                    ),
        true);
```

PHP:

```
function xor_string($string, $key) {
    $str_len = strlen($string);
    $key_len = strlen($key);

    for($i = 0; $i < $str_len; $i++) {
        $string[$i] = $string[$i] ^ $key[$i % $key_len];
    }

    return $string;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function xor_string(string, key) {
    string = string.split('');
    key = key.split('');
    var str_len = string.length;
    var key_len = key.length;
    var String_fromCharCode = String.fromCharCode;

    for(var i = 0; i < str_len; i++) {
        string[i] = String_fromCharCode(string[i].charCodeAt(0) ^ key[i % key_len].charCodeAt(0));
    }

    return string.join('');
}
```

Comment: Of course most of the world is non-ASCII so this is very limited. Copnsider a soltion that it generally usable.

Comment: It's usable, i mentioned that i use to encode the string to base64 and then XOR it, i wouldn't post this if it wouldn't work